# Facebook JS API - How to redirect user after login

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have the following code:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response.session) {
            } else {
                FB.ui({
                    method: 'oauth',
                    perms: 'email,publish_stream',
                    },
                    function (response) {
                        if (response && response.installed) {
                           window.location.reload();
                        }
                    });
            }
        });
```

What I want is to basically redirect the user to the same page so that the serverside can use the REST API. Is there anyway to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subscribe to the login event:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
  window.location.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function (response) {
   if (response.session) {
       //user is logged in!
       window.location = document.URL;
   }
});
```