# Facebook redirect after login

Tags: facebook, facebook-canvas, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have read a number of questions and answers, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782515/facebook-js-api-how-to-redirect-user-after-login) on StackOverflow and none works. My question to all responses I have seen are 'does it work in Safari?'.

I am trying to get this to work with Safari. It works on Chrome and Firefox fine. But in Safari the login screen just freezes and I get the "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL" log message.

I have a canvas app. I want to log the user in and redirect them to a page once they have logged in. I am trying to redirect directly after login. I have tried

1. setting `window.top.location` to a facebook url (with some data passed to a signed request as the all_data argument)
2. setting `window.location` to a URL with the same domain as my app.
3. subscribing to the `auth.login` event and putting the redirect there
4. putting the redirect in the callback to login

None of these works for Safari. I'm starting to think that there's no way to do it.

```
function doSomething()
{
  FB.login(
    function(loginResponse)
    {
      if (loginResponse.authResponse)
      {
        window.top.location = "my url"
      }
    },
    {
      scope:"some,scope"
    }
  );
}
}
```

In response to Nitzan Tomer, here is the equivalent code which doesn't work with Safari but does work with others:

```
function myThing()
{
  FB.login(function(loginResponse)
    {
      if (loginResponse.authResponse)
      {
        FB.api('/me', function(response)
        { 
          window.location = "http://my_app.com?x=" + response.xyz;
        });
        }
    },
    {
      scope:"scopes"
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was occurring slightly earlier in the login process and the callback never got called. I did set a breakpoint in the callback (which wasn't called) but I thought the breakpoint might not work for some reason (perhaps because it was being executed in the context of another window).

Anyway, the problem was that the channel file (which the docs seem to suggest are optional) wasn't working properly, and this caused a problem with Safari but not with other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This is not much of a solution to your problem, but more of a "workaround", though it still uses `window.top.location` but not from a callback so maybe it will work (I'm just not sure where the callback is executed, since it's the fb sdk that executes it, maybe they call it from the fb iframe inside your iframe).

Instead of using client side authentication, you can use the [server side flow](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/).
The entire process is happening on the top window, since it starts by you redirecting the user to the oauth dialog using `window.top.location`.

When the process ends facebook redirects the user to your redirect_uri, and there you can simply redirect the user where ever you want.

I hope this will help.
Also, you should be aware that in the [Facebook Platform Policies](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/) it states:

> 13 . The primary purpose of your Canvas or Page Tab app on Facebook must not be to simply redirect users out of the Facebook experience
>   and onto an external site.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it. For clarification, I am just trying to move between screens in my canvas app, not going to another site.

Comment: So why do you want to use `window.top.location`? Just use `window.location` to change the url of your iframe and not the main window.

Comment: That's the whole point. That method works for Chrome and FF, but it just doesn't work for Safari.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've updated my question with code about as close as possible to my real code.

Comment: The error that you posted ("Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL") usually does not block the execution, but it is just logged. Maybe there's another error in safari? First of all it should be `window.location.href = ...` and not just `window.location`, also maybe add a try/catch at the beginning of the function to check.

Comment: Yeah the Facebook triggers those left right and centre. I included it for completeness as it was the only logged error message.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't know if you're familiar with the expression that 'FFS' expands to but ... that. It was a typo in the channel file URL. I'll delete the question, but I'd like to say thank you first!